# Angular2 replace attribute when value contains curly brackets

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm checking the value of this attribute `dummy-data` but when the value contains curly brackets Angular2 is renaming the attribute

[In Editor](https://monosnap.com/file/qHi9G2XFS87J8qlmNNIG3HNP6AGaG8)

`<c-heading-image dummy-data="images.{{content.image}}"></c-heading-image>`

[In Browser](https://monosnap.com/file/jUG63JLY0CLlvwmaVUEvE11iwCBuJH)

`<c-heading-image ng-reflect-dummy-data="images.regular"></c-heading-image>`

How can I prevent Angular2 from renaming the Attribute

I'm using Ionic framework 2

Answer (score 0):

Angular2 renames attributes like this in development to assist with debugging. If you put your application in production mode, you should find that the attribute has the name you expect. You can do this by calling enableProdMode() like this:

```
import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';

enableProdMode();
bootstrap(....);
```

Comment: Enabling Production mode removed the attribute altogether.